# Image linking in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

I would like my users to be able to add an image LINK (not an uploaded file) to a ckeditor field and it display the actual image (IMG tag). I can't seem to work out how to do it, the upload works fine but it's not this that I'm after.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Try this plugin: ckeditor.com/addon/base64image

1. download https://github.com/nmmf/base64image/archive/master.zip
2. extract folder base64image to folder ckeditor/plugins
3. into html code write you html element editor and script:

   CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', { toolbar: [{ name: 'about', items: [ 'base64image','About' ] },],
                                  extraPlugins: 'base64image'
                                   });

4.If you want to disable file browser, comment this lines in the file /base64image/dialogs/base64image.js :

```
/*{
                type: "hbox",
                widths: ["70px"],
                children: [
                    {
                        type: "checkbox",
                        id: "filecheckbox",
                        style: "margin-top:5px",
                        label: editor.lang.common.upload+":"
                    },
                    {
                        type: "file",
                        id: "file",
                        label: "",
                        onChange: function(){ imagePreview("file"); }
                    }
                ]
            },*/

//fileCB = this.getContentElement("tab-source", "filecheckbox");

//fileCB.getInputElement().on("click", function(){ imagePreview("file"); });
```